# How to preserve shell script line spacing when reading stdout?

Tags: bash, shell, go

I am executing a shell script on Windows 10 via Cygwin, reading stdout and stderr to a string, and passing that string to a struct that is used to execute an html template.

The issue is that the spacing of the output is not preserved after executing the template. Here is how I am executing a command and setting the command output to my data struct.

```
var outbuf, errbuf bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &outbuf
cmd.Stderr = &errbuf

err = cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error running command: %s", err)
    data.Output = errbuf.String()
    return data
}
log.Printf("%v", outbuf.String())
data.Output = outbuf.String()
return data
```

The log.Printf would produce something like this, which is what I expect. New lines are shown.

```
If the same archived message file is in both system/logs and archived_logs, it will be searched/counted twice!

====X1-SC1====



Done
```

After the command is run and my data struct is updated, the data is executed with an html template.

```
err = t.Execute(w, data)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to execute html: %v", err)))
    return
    }
}
```

```
<div style="text-align:center">
   {{.Output}}
</div>
```

After browsing to where my project is exposed, I see the output I expect but it's all on one line. The spacing was not preserved. It seems that html/template execution is removing extra white space, or lines, or something like that. Is there a way around this?

```
If the same archived message file is in both system/logs and archived_logs, it will be searched/counted twice! Maybe it'll be fixed in the future.. ====X1-SC1==== Done
```

Comment: This comment is correct. If you answer, I can mark it accepted. @CeriseLimón

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View the source and will find that whitespace is preserved by the template. The problem is that the browser is collapsing sequences of whitespace. See [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).